# What is 'd3.svg.axis()' in d3 version 4?

Tags: d3.js

How can I replace below lines with the new version of D3 API?

I have already replaced `scale.linear()` with `scaleLinear()`

```
var xRange = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([OIResults.min,OIResults.max]).range([40, 360]);

var yRange = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(y_domain).range([360, 40]);
```

Below Lines need to be replaced according to the new API:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xRange).tickFormat(function(d) { return d.x;});
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yRange).orient("left");
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The D3 v4 API [is here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v4.13.0/API.md#axes-d3-axis). According to the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md):

> D3 4.0 provides default styles and shorter syntax. In place of d3.svg.axis and axis.orient, D3 4.0 now provides four constructors for each orientation: d3.axisTop, d3.axisRight, d3.axisBottom, d3.axisLeft.

Therefore, those lines should be:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xRange).tickFormat(function(d){ return d.x;});
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yRange);
```

---

PS: I'm assuming that you want the ticks to be below the axis, which is normally the case, since you didn't show the `orient` in your original lines.

PPS: At the time of the writing the linked documentation applies to D3 v4. Caveat, lector: that can change at any time (see comments below).

Comment: It may be worth linking to the v4 API reference as the question specifically asked for it. For now you are linking to the module d3-axis v1.0.8 which happens to be the version included in D3 v4, this may, however, change anytime soon. In these cases I try to use links like https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v4.13.0/API.md#axes-d3-axis referring to the v4.13.0 tag. What's your opinion on this?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems to me that if you click `"Axes (d3-axis)"` or any other section in that link you shared it goes to the same page, which is https://github.com/d3/d3-axis. So, linking the specific version doesn't seem to make difference regarding the redirected README.md file.

Comment: You are right. Too bad. Even worse, I cannot think of a way around this. Every linking to documentation is thus prone to become outdated at any time. On the other hand, it's the very reason why links are considered somewhat suspicious on the site.