# How to add grid lines to a Chart in Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm new to Javascript, and through exploring various websites I have created a draggable points line chart. The data points are movable and the line connecting the dots is made invisible. The data points will move vertically only. I want to have grid lines with this chart. I tried but have not able to achieve it. Can someone help me with adding gridlines to this chart? I have attached the code that I have build.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>

<svg width="500" height="350"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

function make_x_axis() {        
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
         .orient("bottom")
         .ticks(5)
}

function make_y_axis() {        
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
}   

let points = d3.range(1, 10).map(function(i) {
    return [i * width / 10, 50 + Math.random() * (height - 100)];
});

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });
    
let drag = d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragstarted)
        .on('drag', dragged)
        .on('end', dragended);
        
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'zoom')
    .attr('cursor', 'move')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    
svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

svg.append("g")         
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
         )

 var focus = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[0]; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[1]; }));

focus.append("path")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);

focus.selectAll('circle')
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5.0)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d[0]);  })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .style('fill', 'steelblue');

focus.selectAll('circle')
        .call(drag);

focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);
 
 
focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
    .call(yAxis);


function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed('active', true);
}

function dragged(d) {
    //d[0] = x.invert(d3.event.x);
    d[1] = y.invert(d3.event.y);
    d3.select(this)
        //.attr('cx', x(d[0]))
        .attr('cy', y(d[1]))
    focus.select('path').attr('d', line);
}

function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed('active', false);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I think you meant JavaScript (not Java) in your first sentence. Could you share what you've tried already, as this code is just from D3 Observable

Comment: Hi Alicia ,Thanks for the reply.  yes its a D3 Observable code and this is what my requirement is . I have edited the code to add the gridlines that I have tried .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you're using to append the grid is from v3 of d3.js. d3v4 added `d3.axisLeft()` and `d3.axisBottom()`, etc. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465283/what-is-d3-svg-axis-in-d3-version-4/40465701).

Also, the `translate` coordinates you're using for the grid is not correct, I've adjusted some of the values so it fits the graph.

Here's a working example:

```html
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>-->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>

<svg width="500" height="350"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.axisBottom(x)
        // .scale(x)
        //  .orient("bottom")
         .ticks(5)
}

function make_y_axis() {
    return d3.axisLeft(y)
        // .scale(y)
        // .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
}

let points = d3.range(1, 10).map(function(i) {
    return [i * width / 10, 50 + Math.random() * (height - 100)];
});

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });



let drag = d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragstarted)
        .on('drag', dragged)
        .on('end', dragended);

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'zoom')
    .attr('cursor', 'move')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')



// svg.append("g")
//         .attr("class", "grid")
//         .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
//         .call(make_x_axis()
//             .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
//             .tickFormat("")
//         )
//
// svg.append("g")
//     .attr("class", "grid")
//     .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
//     // .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + margin.top) + ")")
//     .call(make_y_axis()
//     .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
//     .tickFormat("")
//          )
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${height + margin.top})`)
      .call(make_x_axis()
          .tickSize(-height)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

  // add the Y gridlines
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
      .call(make_y_axis()
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

 var focus = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[0]; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[1]; }));

focus.append("path")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);

focus.selectAll('circle')
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5.0)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d[0]);  })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .style('fill', 'steelblue');

focus.selectAll('circle')
        .call(drag);

focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);


focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
    .call(yAxis);


function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed('active', true);
}

function dragged(d) {
    //d[0] = x.invert(d3.event.x);
    d[1] = y.invert(d3.event.y);
    d3.select(this)
        //.attr('cx', x(d[0]))
        .attr('cy', y(d[1]))
    focus.select('path').attr('d', line);
}

function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed('active', false);
}

</script>
```

In case you're wondering why the lines are "broken", it's because of the white best-fitting line overlapping with the grid.

Line revealed:

```html
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>-->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>

<svg width="500" height="350"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.axisBottom(x)
        // .scale(x)
        //  .orient("bottom")
         .ticks(5)
}

function make_y_axis() {
    return d3.axisLeft(y)
        // .scale(y)
        // .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
}

let points = d3.range(1, 10).map(function(i) {
    return [i * width / 10, 50 + Math.random() * (height - 100)];
});

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });



let drag = d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragstarted)
        .on('drag', dragged)
        .on('end', dragended);

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'zoom')
    .attr('cursor', 'move')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')



// svg.append("g")
//         .attr("class", "grid")
//         .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
//         .call(make_x_axis()
//             .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
//             .tickFormat("")
//         )
//
// svg.append("g")
//     .attr("class", "grid")
//     .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
//     // .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + margin.top) + ")")
//     .call(make_y_axis()
//     .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
//     .tickFormat("")
//          )
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${height + margin.top})`)
      .call(make_x_axis()
          .tickSize(-height)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

  // add the Y gridlines
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
      .call(make_y_axis()
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

 var focus = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[0]; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[1]; }));

focus.append("path")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black") // modified
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);

focus.selectAll('circle')
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5.0)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d[0]);  })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .style('fill', 'steelblue');

focus.selectAll('circle')
        .call(drag);

focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);


focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
    .call(yAxis);


function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed('active', true);
}

function dragged(d) {
    //d[0] = x.invert(d3.event.x);
    d[1] = y.invert(d3.event.y);
    d3.select(this)
        //.attr('cx', x(d[0]))
        .attr('cy', y(d[1]))
    focus.select('path').attr('d', line);
}

function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed('active', false);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks much @Parzival . My requirement does not want the lines to be shown between the dots , so I made it as white . This is perfect .